# Calculating forest canopy density and advanced vegetation index in ArcGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, vegetation-index, canopy-height-model

While performing raster calculator operation in ArcGIS for Advanced Vegetation Index ( in calculating forest canopy density), the results show only 2 values i.e high (1) and low ( 0), **instead of a range of values**.The low values considered are of that of the background no-data values.

What could be the possible problem in the operation ?

I am using the formula :

```
AVI = (("ref5"+1) * (256-"ref4") * ("ref5"-"ref4")) ^ (1/3)
```

where ref5, ref4 are bands 5, 4 corresponding to Landsat 8 image, converted into TOA reflectance values.

Answer (score 2):

I think the equation in the raster calculator should be written as follows:

```
(("TOA_B5.tif"+1) * (256-"TOA_B4.tif") * ("TOA_B5.tif"-"TOA_B4.tif"))**(1.0/3.0)
```

- **: means power
- convert (1/3) integer division into float division (1.0/3.0)

You need to change `"TOA_B5.tif"` and `"TOA_B4.tif"` to the corresponding layer names exist in the table of content in ArcMap

Comment: I updated my answer, you need to remove `AVI = ` in raster calculator. The above equation was tested and should be OK

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Can you please tell me what formula have you used to get the TOA_B5 values ?

Comment: @PrabhashiniMohapatra that is another question different from the one you asked. In GIS.SE, you can ask only one question at a time. If you have a new question, you need to write on a separate thread. Please prepare a detailed question of what have you tried and what formula you used when calculating the TOA.

Comment: Hi. I tried this formula but I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: What is the format of your raster data? I used `tif` as you can see in my answer.

Comment: I have also used tif data.